# How can I calculate the time difference between two lists of dates/times using 365 day format in python?

Tags: python, regex, list, time

I have two lists of dates and times in the following format:
YYYY:DDD:HH:MM:SS:mmm
(mmm is miliseconds).

I am getting these times from another list using regular expressions.

```
for line in start_list 
    start_time = re.search(r'((\d\d\d\d):(\d*):(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d\d))')
for line in end_list 
    end_time = re.search(r'((\d\d\d\d):(\d*):(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d\d))')
```

I could do a for loop cycling through start_time, and have a counter to keep track of the current line for end_time. I'm not really sure the best way to execute it. I cant seem to figure out how to cycle through each line in each list to calculate the time difference between them. Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you've opted to use Regular Expressions and not something like [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: I guess the standard approach is to use datetime library to transform all elements in datetime format  using strptime(https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime)  and use relativedelta (https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)  Do you need to do this manually?

Comment: The only reason I didnt use strptime() is due to not knowing much about it. I have only seen examples using a standard date format using months, and not one for 365 day format. if it is easier to use strip time I can use that as well. I also thought I would have to use the groups for day, hour, minute, and seconds to calculate the total seconds and find the difference between start and end time. I'm relatively inexperienced at this so if there is a more efficient way I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to datetime objects and then just subtract the first series to the second as e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

start_list_pts=[date.replace(":",".") for date in start_list]
end_list_pts=[date.replace(":",".") for date in end_list]

start_datetimes=pd.to_datetime(start_list_pts,format='%Y.%j.%H.%M.%S.%f')
end_datetimes=pd.to_datetime(end_list_pts,format='%Y.%j.%H.%M.%S.%f')

dts=start_datetimes-end_datetimes
```

Your milliseconds were not a fraction of your seconds that's why I changed the separator to points. You can of course also only change the last one!